# Rails find using where in one to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model that has many "states":

```
class User
    has_many states

class State
    belongs_to user
```

Now, I'd like to go through each User and find all the Users with that state something like...

```
state = State.last
# I want to get all the users where state appears in ANY user's user.states

User.where(state IN user.states.. )
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a join to get the user's that have the state:

```
User.joins(:states).where(state: 'some_type_of_state')
```

The other way is by grabbing all the user id's that have the specific state, and then querying for those users:

```
user_ids = State.where(state: 'some_type_of_state').pluck(:user_id)
users = User.where(id: user_ids)
```

The last query typically doesn't perform as well.